# DirectConnect (dc++) connection problem on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, firewall, file-sharing, dc++

I'm setting up a Direct Connect hub for our LAN party to distribute game patches etc. Have been doing that for years with few problems. I've now upgraded to Windows 7 (RC) and no one can connect to me. I can connect to the local hub (running port 411)

I am now testing with 2 computers on a local LAN (same switch) I can connect to the other computer and see its files, but not to the new Windows 7.

I've granted dcplusplus.exe access in the windows 7 firewall. I have also completely switched of the windows 7 firewall with no success. I have installed no other firewalls.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused when you dont run your DC++ app as administrator , i know for a fact that this what happened to me. If you dont run as admin 2 things will happen. People will generally not be able to connect to you without you granting them a slot and any files you hash will not be saved. So the next time you start your app it will start reshashing all the files again.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does have an official [Windows 7 Support Forum located](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/w7itpro/) . It is supported by product specialists as well as engineers and support teams. You may want to check the threads available there for additional assistance and feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try also :

- completely turning off UAC
- turning off ALL antiviruses
- setting the compatibility mode of dcplusplus.exe to XP